# Thymeleaf th:text displaying wrong value on encoded parameter

Tags: thymeleaf

The URL of the template is: 
http://localhost:8080/login?error=Usu%E1rio%20inexistente%20ou%20senha%20inv%E1lida

where, for example, %E1 is á

I'm trying to display the value of the param error on the page using this code:

but a wrong value with special character is being displayed.

Comment: the code is th:text="${param.error}"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

I see two ways you can try:

**1) Use the utility for an `HttpServletRequest`:**

```
<p th:utext="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('error')}">[error message]</p>
```

This is getting the value of the `error` parameter from the request.

**2) Use the typical usage for getting the value of a param:**

```
<p th:utext="${param.error}">[error message]</p>
```

In either case, you can use `th:if` to check for null.  You can use `utext` to get the unescaped text so that unusual characters display.

Also, check that your character encoding is set to UTF-8.  In your config, it would look something like:

```
resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

or

```
resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: It is still displaying: Usu�rio inexistente ou senha inv�lida

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to decode the URL, I first encoded the error message where it was generated using `URLEncoder.encode(errorMessage)`. So, the URL changed to `http://localhost:8080/login?error=Usuário+inexistente+ou+senha+inválida`. Then, I didn't need to decode. I only used `th:text="${param.msgError}`